# Does OpenThread use frequency/channel hopping?

Tags: openthread

I am evaluating openthread for a project and is trying to find any information about whether it uses channel hopping. I've read the thread spec and found something about beacons on different channels when joining a network, but nothing more after that. I've also had a look through the code but must have missed the relevant sections.

What I am asking is simply does it stick to one 802.15.4 channel like ZigBee or does it use the whole available spectrum, like WirelessHART?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Thread Specification](http://threadgroup.org/ThreadSpec) uses the standard IEEE 802.15.4-2006 MAC and does not employ channel hopping - all devices on a network are configured to communicate on a single channel.  The Thread Specification does include mechanisms for dynamically changing the network's channel over the air, along with other network configuration parameters.

Comment: When does this dynamic changing happen? have I understood the spec correctly (section 8) that Active Operational Data Sets, which include the channel, can be changed when routing fails? Is this configurable?

Comment: Network configuration changes (including channel) are initiated and disseminated through Thread's Mesh Commissioning protocol.  The [Thread Specification](http://threadgroup.org/ThreadSpec) provides all the details.  While Thread provides the mechanisms for making configuration changes, it does not specify the policy.  The higher layer could implement policy based on arbitrary inputs.